# Flutter Dart: BLoC Pattern to update data in two different StreamBuilders

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, stream-builder

EDIT: Posted my Sign in Form.

On my Login/Register with email and password screen I have a `Scaffold` with an `AppBar` and a `body: List<Widget> FormColumn` with the latter being on a separate file and imported.

On my form file I have StreamBuilder listening to a bloc containing data and a `FlatButton` that switches the form logic from *Sign In* logic to *Register Logic* see picture below and I made a second `StreamBuilder` on my Scaffold like so:

```
class SignInDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  final EmailPwSignBloc bloc;
  const SignInDialog({Key key, @required this.bloc}) : super(key: key);
  
  // this is my static function
  // it builds the screen 
  // used 'makeScreenWithbloc' because create is already
  // used in this file

  static Widget makeScreenWithbloc(BuildContext context){
    AuthService authService = Provider.of<AuthService>(context);
    return Provider<EmailPwSignBloc>(
      create: (context) => EmailPwSignBloc(authService: authService),
      dispose: (context, bloc) => bloc.dispose(),
      child: Consumer<EmailPwSignBloc>(builder: (context, blocFromProvider, _) => SignInDialog(bloc: blocFromProvider,)),
    );
  }
  static void create(BuildContext context){
    // ADDING STATE TO THE APPBAR
  }

  @override
  _SignInDialogState createState() => _SignInDialogState();
}

class _SignInDialogState extends State<SignInDialog> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: StreamBuilder<EmailSignInModel>(
            stream: widget.bloc.getEmailSignInModel,
            initialData: EmailSignInModel(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              final EmailSignInModel data = snapshot.data;
              return Text(data.appBarText);
            }
          ), // TODO: Bool SignIn/Register
          centerTitle: true),
      body: Container(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                child: Card(
                  child: SignInFormBlocCompatible.create(context),)
                ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

To be able to update the *appBar title*.

Here is the sign in form:

```
class SignInFormBlocCompatible extends StatefulWidget
    with EmailAndPasswordStringValidator {
  final EmailPwSignBloc bloc;

  SignInFormBlocCompatible({
    Key key,
    @required this.bloc,
  }) : super(key: key);

  static Widget create(context) {
    AuthService authService = Provider.of<AuthService>(context);
    return Provider<EmailPwSignBloc>(
      create: (context) => EmailPwSignBloc(authService: authService),
      child: Consumer<EmailPwSignBloc>(
        builder: (context, bloc, _) => SignInFormBlocCompatible(bloc: bloc),
      ),
      dispose: (context, bloc) => bloc.dispose(),
    );
  }

  @override
  _SignInFormState createState() => _SignInFormState();
}

class _SignInFormState extends State<SignInFormBlocCompatible> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<EmailSignInModel>(
      stream: widget.bloc.getEmailSignInModel,
      initialData: EmailSignInModel(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        final EmailSignInModel model = snapshot.data;
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 30, 15, 15),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: _listOfFormElements(model),
          ),
        );
      }
    );
  }
  static TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  static TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();

  // creating the submit function
  Future<void> _submit(EmailSignInModel model) async {
    // if it is on sign in use sign in function ELSE use register function
    try {
      await widget.bloc.submit();
      Navigator.pop(context);
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    } 
  }

  List<Widget> _listOfFormElements(EmailSignInModel model) {
   Login_or_reg defaultType = model.loginOrReg;
    // validating button text
    var validatingButtonText =
        defaultType == Login_or_reg.signIn ? 'Log In' : 'Create Account';

    // switch between login or register button
    var switchLogInOrRegisterText = defaultType == Login_or_reg.signIn
        ? "Don't have an account? Register"
        : 'Have an account? Log in';

    // this function is used to switch between function
    // when switching it clears the fields of text
    void _signInOrReg(model) {
        model.loginOrReg == Login_or_reg.signIn ? widget.bloc.updateModel(email: '', password: '', submitted: false, appBarText: 'Register', loginOrReg: Login_or_reg.register): widget.bloc.updateModel(email: '', password: '', appBarText: 'Log In', submitted: false, loginOrReg: Login_or_reg.signIn);
        _emailController.clear();
        _passwordController.clear();
    }

    return [
      // email
      TextFormField(
          autocorrect: false,
          controller: _emailController,
          onChanged: (value) => widget.bloc.updateModel(email: value),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            enabled: model.enabled == true,
            hintText: 'example@example.com',
            labelText: 'eMail',
          )),
      SizedBox(height: 10),
      // password
      TextFormField(
          autocorrect: false,
          onChanged: (value) => widget.bloc.updateModel(password: value),
          controller: _passwordController,
          obscureText: true,
          onEditingComplete: () => _submit(model),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Your password here',
            labelText: 'Password',
          )),
      SizedBox(height: 20),

      // my sign in/register button
      CustomFlatButton(
        text: validatingButtonText,
        color: Colors.indigo,
        textColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 10),

      // my bool signin/register button
      CustomFlatButton(
        text: switchLogInOrRegisterText,
        color: Color(0xff),
        callback: model.enabled ? () => _signInOrReg(model) : null,
        textColor: Colors.indigo,
      )
    ];
  }
}
```

Here is my sign in bloc:

```
class EmailPwSignBloc {
  final AuthService authService;
  EmailPwSignBloc({@required this.authService});

  StreamController<EmailSignInModel> _streamController =
      StreamController<EmailSignInModel>();

  // GETTER
  Stream<EmailSignInModel> get getEmailSignInModel => _streamController.stream;
  // SETTER
  set _setEmailSignInModel(EmailSignInModel model) =>
      _streamController.sink.add(model);
  EmailSignInModel _modelInstance = EmailSignInModel();
  void dispose() {
    _streamController.close();
  }

  // changing model values
  void updateModel({
    String email,
    String password,
    Login_or_reg loginOrReg,
    String appBarText,
    bool submitted,
    bool enabled,
  }) {
    // updating model
    _modelInstance = _modelInstance.copyWith(
      email: email,
      password: password,
      appBarText: appBarText,
      loginOrReg: loginOrReg,
      submitted: submitted,
      enabled: enabled,
    );
    _setEmailSignInModel = _modelInstance;
  }

  Future<void> submit() async {
    updateModel(submitted: true, enabled: false);
    // if it is on sign in use sign in function ELSE use register function
    try {
      if (_modelInstance.loginOrReg == Login_or_reg.signIn) {
        await authService.signInWithEmail(
            _modelInstance.email, _modelInstance.password);
      } else {
        await authService.registerWithEmail(
            _modelInstance.email, _modelInstance.password);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error occurred and rethrown.');  
      print(e.toString());
      rethrow;
    } finally {
      updateModel(enabled: true);
    }
  }
```

and here is my sign in model:

```
enum Login_or_reg {
  signIn,
  register,
}

class EmailSignInModel {
  final String email;
  final String password;
  final String appBarText;
  final Login_or_reg loginOrReg;
  final bool submitted;
  final bool enabled;

  EmailSignInModel({
    this.email = '',
    this.password = '',
    this.appBarText = 'Log In', // TODO: change default appBar text 
    this.loginOrReg = Login_or_reg.signIn,
    this.submitted = false,
    this.enabled = true,
  });

  EmailSignInModel copyWith({
    String email,
    String password,
    String appBarText,
    Login_or_reg loginOrReg,
    bool submitted,
    bool enabled,
  }) {
    // TODO: Take off leText & print 
    String leText;
    leText = appBarText ?? this.appBarText;
    print(leText);
    return EmailSignInModel(
      email: email ?? this.email,
      password: password ?? this.password,
      appBarText: appBarText ?? this.appBarText,
      enabled: enabled ?? this.enabled,
      submitted: submitted ?? this.submitted,
      loginOrReg: loginOrReg ?? this.loginOrReg,
    );
  }
}
```

Problem: Everything works fine except for the AppBar Title. Am I doing something wrong in the implementation?

[image: Loginc/Register Screen]

Comment: I'm afraid there is no way to tell what's wrong without seeing a [mcve].

Comment: @nvoigt I will share a minimal version in a few.

Comment: @nvoigt I just edited.

Comment: To be honest that is a lot of boilerplate code that you will have to write again and again and again. Have you thought about using the packages "bloc" and "flutter_bloc" so you only have to write what is necessary for your business logic, instead of implementing the bloc pattern every time you write a bloc? I cannot spot the mistake, but maybe you can when you boil it down to what is necessary to write yourself.